# Is Sklearn TFIDF vectorizer thread safe?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I have built a TfidfVectorizer and fit it to my dataset

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=ner_tokenizer, stop_words='english')
tfidf.fit(documents)
```

I now want to do `tfidf.transform()` in multiple threads. Is this safe to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see `transform` only reads `self` but does not modify it, so it should be thread-safe.

`transform()` calls `TfidfTransformer.transform()`, `CountVectorizer.transform()`, `check_is_fitted()` and indirectly `CountVectorizer._validate_vocabulary()`, `CountVectorizer._check_vocabulary()`, `CountVectorizer._count_vocab()` and `normalize()` and some more in deeper levels which don't modify. There might still be some magic going on, but I could not find anything.